# receive SMS messages for Listview Item by using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

1. SMSReceiver.java

   ```
   public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   String str = ""; 
   if (bundle != null) {

       Object [] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");

       SmsMessage [] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
       String [] lmsg = new String[2048];
       for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
           msgs[i] = SmsMessage
                   .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
           str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()
                   + "\n " +
                   msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString()
                   +"\n";
       }
       for (int j = 0; j < lmsg.length ; j++) {
           lmsg[j] = str;
       } Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
     }  
   }
   ```

2.RedirectActivity

```
public class RedirectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.setClass(RedirectActivity.this, ParentActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
   } 
 }
```

I want to get data from SMS to ParentActivity.

1. SMSReceiver : receive sms messages
2. RedirectActivity : deliver messages to ParentActivity
3. ParentActivity : get data from redirectActivity by Intent

And I've got problem between SMSReceiver and RedirectActivity. It doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching sms details in service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996446/catching-sms-details-in-service)

Comment: @Hhhh please check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one bro**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static SmsListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            //You must check here if the sender is your provider and not another one with same text.

            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();

            //Pass on the text to our listener.
            mListener.messageReceived(messageBody);
        }
    }

    public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

**Interface Listener**

```
public interface SmsListener {
    public void messageReceived(String messageText);
}
```

**Activity get Mesage**

```
 IncomingSms.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
            Log.d("Text", messageText);
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "Message: " + messageText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

**Dont forget this manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

 <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```